Mongodb TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')
models.tsx
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    username: {type: String},
    hashedPassword: {type: String},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    image: {type: String},
    orders: {type: Number},
    revenue: {type: Number},
    location: {type: String},
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean},
    isPending: {type: Boolean},
    role: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    isApproved: {type: Boolean},
  },
  {timestamps: true}
);

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  isApproved: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  id: {
    type: String,
  },
});

export const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export const Product =
  mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);


team/page
"use server";
import {redirect} from "next/navigation";
import {auth} from "@/server/auth";
import {getRoleStatus} from "@/server/actions/get-role-status";
import db from "@/server/db";
import {User} from "@/lib/models";
import AnalyticsCard from "../../components/dashboard/analytics-card";
import TeamList from "../../components/teams/team-list";
import {z} from "zod";
import {TeamSchema} from "@/types/team-schema";
export type Team = z.infer<typeof TeamSchema>;

export default async function Page() {
  await db();
  const team = await User.find();

  const session = await auth();
  const role = await getRoleStatus();

  if (!session) {
    redirect("/");
  }

  return (
    <AnalyticsCard title="Team" subTitle="Approved Member and Pending Member">
      <div className="p-6">
        <TeamList data={team} role={role!} />
      </div>
    </AnalyticsCard>
  );
}


team-list.tsx
"use client";
import TeamCard from "./teams-card";

interface TeamListProps {
  data: Team[];
  role: boolean;
}
export type Team = {
  email: string;
  name?: string | null;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
  isApproved?: boolean;
  image?: string | null;
  location?: string | null;
};
const TeamList = ({data, role}: TeamListProps) => {
  const approvedMembers = data.filter((member) => member.isApproved);
  const pendingMembers = data.filter((member) => !member.isApproved);

  return (
    <div className="space-y-16">
      <div>
        <h2 className="mb-4">Approved Members</h2>
        <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 gap-8">
          {approvedMembers.map((member, index) => (
          <TeamCard
          key={index}
          name={member.name ?? "Unknown Name"} // 기본값 설정
          image={member.image ?? "/fallbackimage.png"} // 기본 이미지 설정
          email={member.email}
          location={member.location ?? "Unknown Location"} // 기본값 설정
          isAdmin={member.isAdmin ?? false} // 기본값 설정
          isPending={false}
          role={role}
        />
        
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2 className="mb-4">Pending Members</h2>
        <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 gap-8">
          {pendingMembers.map((member, index) => (
           <TeamCard
           key={index}
           name={member.name ?? "Unknown Name"} // 기본값 설정
           image={member.image ?? "/fallbackimage.png"} // 기본 이미지 설정
           email={member.email}
           location={member.location ?? "Unknown Location"} // 기본값 설정
           isAdmin={member.isAdmin ?? false} // 기본값 설정
           isPending={false}
           role={role}
         />
         
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TeamList;


teams-card.tsx
import { Card } from "../ui/card";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import {
  approveTeamMember,
  declineTeamMember,
  deleteTeamMember,
  updateTeamMember,
} from "@/server/actions/team-actions";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTrigger,
  DialogContent,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogFooter,
} from "../ui/dialog";
import { Checkbox } from "../ui/checkbox";
import { useState } from "react";
import db from "@/server/db";

export interface TeamMemberCardProps {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  email: string;
  location: string;
  isPending: boolean;
  role: boolean;
}

export default function TeamCard({
  name,
  image,
  isAdmin: initialAdminStatus,
  email,
  location,
  isPending,
  role,
}: TeamMemberCardProps) {
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(initialAdminStatus);
  const imageUrl = image && image !== "no-image" ? image : "/fallbackimage.png";

  // APPROVE TEAM MEMBER FUNCTION
  const handleApproveTeamMember = async () => {
    if (!role) {
      toast.error("You must be an admin to approve a team member");
      return;
    }

    try {
      await db(); // Ensure this only runs once during app initialization
      await approveTeamMember({ email, name });
      toast.success(`${name} has been approved`);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("An error occurred while approving the team member");
    }
  };

  // DECLINE TEAM MEMBER FUNCTION
  const handleDeclineTeamMember = async () => {
    if (!role) {
      toast.error("You must be an admin to decline a team member");
      return;
    }

    try {
      await db();
      await declineTeamMember({ email, name });
      toast.success(`${name} has been declined`);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("An error occurred while declining the team member");
    }
  };

  // UPDATE TEAM MEMBER ROLE FUNCTION
  const handleUpdateRole = async () => {
    if (!role) {
      toast.error("You must be an admin to update roles");
      return;
    }

    try {
      await db();
      await updateTeamMember({ email, isAdmin });
      toast.success(`Role for ${name} has been updated`);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("An error occurred while updating the role");
    }
  };

  // DELETE TEAM MEMBER FUNCTION
  const handleDeleteTeamMember = async () => {
    if (!role) {
      toast.error("You must be an admin to delete a team member.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      await db();
      await deleteTeamMember({ email });
      toast.success(`${name} has been deleted`);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("An error occurred while deleting the team member");
    }
  };

  // HANDLE EDIT/DELETE MODAL
  const handleEditDeleteModal = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (!role) {
      e.preventDefault();
      toast.error("You must be an admin to edit or delete a team member.");
    }
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
}
}

auth.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import {MongoDBAdapter} from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import {LoginSchema} from "@/types/login-schema";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import {User} from "@/lib/models";
import db from "./db";

export const {handlers, auth, signIn, signOut} = NextAuth({
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(db as any),
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);
        if (!validatedFields.success) {
          return null;
        }

        // Destructure the validated data
        const {email, password} = validatedFields.data;
        // Find the user in the database

        const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
        if (!user || !user.hashedPassword) return null;

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
          password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );
        if (passwordMatch) {
          return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
});


the team page is not open because of the model is keep undefiend.
how to debug the code and what is problem
the chat gpt said the model is already exist but i tried to make the new model.
so i tried to not make the same model in this code.
i don't know where is the problem the database is working and no problem.
I was changed the schema and now it's not working..!
